# Checking if an internal tester in Playstore has installed the app or not

Tags: android, testing, statistics, google-play, analytics

I have set up an internal testing channel on the Google Play Store. I have added a few testers for my app but could not find a way to check if a particular tester from the list has installed the app or not.

I think this can be found out in Appstore. 
We would like to know who has installed the app. 
I attempted using the firebase analytics dashboard and play console dashboard for the app as well, app statistics etc, but with no luck. 
Is there a way to find this in Playstore?

Answer (score 1):

The signup for internal testing requires the Google Play email address the user will use to install the app. While I have never found anything more than a count of testers who installed, you can retrieve the current account of the user using the app. It isn't exactly a neat and autonomous process, but you could craft a means to compare the list of potential users to the installed account.

The permission required is `GET_ACCOUNTS` and then you would use [`AccountManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager) to retrieve a list of accounts and iterate through them to see if any match a list of testers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to distribute an Android or IOS application for testing to users is through [***Beta Crashlytics***](http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/).
From there you will be able to see exactly who installed your application and who didn't.
It will let you know from your Fabric panel who has installed the app.

See [documentation here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/beta-walkthrough.html) on how to distribute your apk.

Comment: I wanted to know if Playstore has this feature.

Comment: Not to my knowledge hence I provided an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play does not provide this information. Any feature like this would have to be carefully evaluated on how it affected user privacy.

Comment: Internal testing is done with a specific list of 100 personally submitted email addresses. By responding, they have already confirmed that they are one of the 100 people on that list. That is like demanding that a cashier requesting ID for cigarettes or alcohol not look at the picture because it violates your privacy.